# creating a date from an existing one in HiveQL

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

I'm completely new to Hive and I would really appreciate some help.

I have a date column in my table and I would like to keep month and year of this date. What I would do in excel is the following:

```
datenew= date(year(old_date),month(old_date),1)
```

my old_date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trunc` with `mm` option (for Hive versions 1.2 and later), which will return the first of a month.

```
trunc(dateCol,'MM')
```

If `trunc` is not supported, use

```
date_add(dateCol,1-day(dateCol))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_format` or `trunc` function, or `substr()+concat()`.

Demo:

```
hive> select current_date original_date,
    >               date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-01') `date_format`,
    >               trunc(current_date, 'MM')              `trunc`,
    >               concat(substr(current_date,1,7),'-01') `substr`
    >               ;
OK
original_date   date_format     trunc           substr
2018-05-30      2018-05-01      2018-05-01      2018-05-01
Time taken: 0.093 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNC (date,fmt)` which is a function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model `fmt`. it always return a value of datatype DATE,:

**Example:**

```
hive> select trunc(current_date, 'MM');
OK
2018-05-01

hive> select trunc(current_date, 'YEAR');
OK
2018-01-01
```